# Как изменить положение значения?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Добрый день.
Помогите, пожалуйста, изменить положение значения индикатора вот для 
[этого](https://codepen.io/kazu_codepen/pen/wGmGjv?editors=1000)

```js
// data which need to be fetched
var name = "azerty";
var value = 17;
var gaugeMaxValue = 100; 
// données à calculer 
var percentValue = value / gaugeMaxValue; 
////////////////////////
var needleClient;
(function(){
var barWidth, chart, chartInset, degToRad, repaintGauge,
    height, margin, numSections, padRad, percToDeg, percToRad, 
    percent, radius, sectionIndx, svg, totalPercent, width; 
  percent = percentValue;
  numSections = 1;
  sectionPerc = 1 / numSections / 2;
  padRad = 0.025;
  chartInset = 10;
  // Orientation of gauge:
  totalPercent = .75;
  el = d3.select('.chart-gauge');
  margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 20
  };
  width = el[0][0].offsetWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
  height = width;
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
  barWidth = 40 * width / 300;
  //Utility methods 
  percToDeg = function(perc) {
    return perc * 360;
  };
  percToRad = function(perc) {
    return degToRad(percToDeg(perc));
  };
  degToRad = function(deg) {
    return deg * Math.PI / 180;
  };
  // Create SVG element
  svg = el.append('svg').attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right).attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
  // Add layer for the panel
  chart = svg.append('g').attr('transform', "translate(" + ((width + margin.left) / 2) + ", " + ((height + margin.top) / 2) + ")");
  chart.append('path').attr('class', "arc chart-first");
  chart.append('path').attr('class', "arc chart-second");
  chart.append('path').attr('class', "arc chart-third");
  arc3 = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius - chartInset).innerRadius(radius - chartInset - barWidth)
  arc2 = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius - chartInset).innerRadius(radius - chartInset - barWidth)
  arc1 = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius - chartInset).innerRadius(radius - chartInset - barWidth)
  repaintGauge = function () 
  {
    perc = 0.5;
    var next_start = totalPercent;
    arcStartRad = percToRad(next_start);
    arcEndRad = arcStartRad + percToRad(perc / 3);
    next_start += perc / 3;
    arc1.startAngle(arcStartRad).endAngle(arcEndRad);
    arcStartRad = percToRad(next_start);
    arcEndRad = arcStartRad + percToRad(perc / 3);
    next_start += perc / 3;
    arc2.startAngle(arcStartRad + padRad).endAngle(arcEndRad);
    arcStartRad = percToRad(next_start);
    arcEndRad = arcStartRad + percToRad(perc / 3); 
    arc3.startAngle(arcStartRad + padRad).endAngle(arcEndRad);
    chart.select(".chart-first").attr('d', arc1);
    chart.select(".chart-second").attr('d', arc2);
    chart.select(".chart-third").attr('d', arc3);  
  }
/////////
    var dataset = [{metric:name, value: value}]
    var texts = svg.selectAll("text")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter(); 
    texts.append("text")
         .text(function(){
              return dataset[0].metric;
         })
         .attr('id', "Name")
         .attr('transform', "translate(" + ((width + margin.left) / 6) + ", " + ((height + margin.top) / 1.5) + ")")
         .attr("font-size",25)
         .style("fill", "#000000");
   var trX = 180 - 210 * Math.cos(percToRad(percent / 2)); 
var trY = 195 - 210 * Math.sin(percToRad(percent / 2));
// (180, 195) are the coordinates of the center of the gauge.
displayValue = function() {
                texts.append("text")
                    .text(function(){
                        return dataset[0].value;
                    })
                    .attr('id', "Value")
                    .attr('transform', "translate(" + trX + ", " + trY+ ")")
                    .attr("font-size",18)
                    .style("fill", '#000000');
            }
    texts.append("text")
        .text(function(){
            return 0;
        })
        .attr('id', 'scale0')
        .attr('transform', "translate(" + ((width + margin.left) / 100 ) + ", " + ((height + margin.top) / 2) + ")")
        .attr("font-size", 15)
        .style("fill", "#000000");               
    texts.append("text")
        .text(function(){
            return gaugeMaxValue/2;
        })
        .attr('id', 'scale10')
        .attr('transform', "translate(" + ((width + margin.left) / 2.15 ) + ", " + ((height + margin.top) / 30) + ")")
        .attr("font-size", 15)
        .style("fill", "#000000");               
    texts.append("text")
        .text(function(){
            return gaugeMaxValue;
        })
        .attr('id', 'scale20')
        .attr('transform', "translate(" + ((width + margin.left) / 1.03 ) + ", " + ((height + margin.top) / 2) + ")")
        .attr("font-size", 15)
        .style("fill", "#000000");
  var Needle = (function() {
    //Helper function that returns the `d` value for moving the needle
    var recalcPointerPos = function(perc) {
      var centerX, centerY, leftX, leftY, rightX, rightY, thetaRad, topX, topY;
      thetaRad = percToRad(perc / 2);
      centerX = 0;
      centerY = 0;
      topX = centerX - this.len * Math.cos(thetaRad);
      topY = centerY - this.len * Math.sin(thetaRad);
      leftX = centerX - this.radius * Math.cos(thetaRad - Math.PI / 2);
      leftY = centerY - this.radius * Math.sin(thetaRad - Math.PI / 2);
      rightX = centerX - this.radius * Math.cos(thetaRad + Math.PI / 2);
      rightY = centerY - this.radius * Math.sin(thetaRad + Math.PI / 2);
        return "M " + leftX + " " + leftY + " L " + topX + " " + topY + " L " + rightX + " " + rightY;  
    };
    function Needle(el) {
      this.el = el;
      this.len = width / 2.5;
      this.radius = this.len / 8;
    }
    Needle.prototype.render = function() {
      this.el.append('circle').attr('class', 'needle-center').attr('cx', 0).attr('cy', 0).attr('r', this.radius); 
      return this.el.append('path').attr('class', 'needle').attr('id', 'client-needle').attr('d', recalcPointerPos.call(this, 0)); 
    };
    Needle.prototype.moveTo = function(perc) {
      var self,
          oldValue = this.perc || 0;
      this.perc = perc;
      self = this;
      // Reset pointer position
      this.el.transition().delay(100).ease('quad').duration(200).select('.needle').tween('reset-progress', function() {
        return function(percentOfPercent) {
          var progress = (1 - percentOfPercent) * oldValue;        
          repaintGauge(progress);
          return d3.select(this).attr('d', recalcPointerPos.call(self, progress));
        };
      });
      this.el.transition().delay(300).ease('bounce').duration(1500).select('.needle').tween('progress', function() {
        return function(percentOfPercent) {
          var progress = percentOfPercent * perc;        
          repaintGauge(progress);
          return d3.select(this).attr('d', recalcPointerPos.call(self, progress));
        };
      });
    };   
    return Needle;
  })();
  needle = new Needle(chart);
  needle.render();
  needle.moveTo(percent);
  setTimeout(displayValue, 1350);
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <style type="text/css" src="gauge.css">
     .chart-gauge
   {
     width: 400px;
     margin: 100px auto  
    } 
   .chart-first
   {
    fill: #9FBD35;
   }
   .chart-second
   {
    fill: #F2BA3A;
   }
            .chart-third
            {
                fill: #FB3033;
            }
  
   .needle, .needle-center
   {
    fill: #000000;
   }
            .text {
                color: "#112864";
                font-size: 16px;
            }
            

   svg {
     font: 10px sans-serif;
   }
            

  </style>

 </head>
 <body>
       
            
        <div class="chart-gauge"></div>

                
     
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./gaugeClient.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./labels.js"></script>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
 </body>

</html>
```

Мне нужно чтоб значение было в одной точке (справа), а еще лучше вынести его в отдельный блок. Не сильна в JS, объясните как это можно реализовать.
Спасибо.

Comment: Добавь скрипты в вопрос.

Comment: @Qwertiy а, ну да, добавила

Comment: Вот так - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NgbboJ ?